# Would people prefer DST if instead asked if they wanted to just get up an hour early for work for most of the year?

Tags: time

A [study](https://www.cbsnews.com/news/more-americans-prefer-daylight-savings-to-standard-time-cbs-news-poll/) showed more americans prefer to stay on DST, though not a majority. A majority would retain at least some standard time, either switching or staying on standard. I haven't seen a study where they instead ask people if they would prefer to keep the clocks the same, and just get up an hour early for most of the year. Is there evidence that it would be expected that this would have an effect on the results? Though the outcome would be the same concerning when people get up.

Comment: There are a lot of other things on the clock besides peoples' jobs that they don't get to set the time for.

Comment: Yes everyone could collectively decide to do things earlier, if they actually wanted to, which is kind of the point.

Comment: But they don't/didn't. Daylight savings time changes behavior.

Comment: They could change schedules without it, the question is would they want to.